# How to implement a 2 parameter lookup table

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm trying to create a structure that takes in two parameters and returns the value that is stored at that point. Something along the lines of rock, paper, scissors.

```
              Rock(0)       Paper(1)      Scissors(2)

Rock(0)      "Tie"(0,0)    "Lose"(0,1)    "Win"(0,2)

Paper(1)     "Win"(1,0)    "Tie"(1,1)     "Lose"(1,2)

Scissors(2)  "Lose"(2,0)   "Win"(2,1)     "Tie"(2,2)
```

Is there a way to do this in a way that will scale well to larger tables?

My initial thought was to create an array of 3D arrays, storing `[x,y,value]`, but looping through every array seems like it would be expensive for larger tables.

```
const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

const array = [
    [0,0,'tie'],  [0,1,'lose'], [0,2,'win'],
    [1,0,'win'],  [1,1,'tie'],  [1,2,'lose'],
    [2,0,'lose'], [2,1,'win'],  [2,2,'tie']
  ];

const result = array.filter((point) => {
    if (x === point[0] && y === point[1]){
      return point
    }
  });

console.log(result[0][2]);
```

Thanks, for any help you can give!

Comment: I might be missing something but wouldn't a simple 2D array work for this?

Comment: Possibly I am over thinking this, How so?

Comment: And for a more general lookup, where it's not just numbers, you can use nested objects.

Comment: The position info in your array is redundant. Each of those conditions correspond to the item coordinates. Just store "win", "lose", "tie" and lookup the result with array[x][y] (or [y][x] I suppose)

Comment: Thanks, just saw my error. I was making it harder than it had to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a 2d array is all you'd need:

```
const rock = 0
const paper = 1
const scissors = 2
const results = [
  [
    'tie',
    'lose',
    'win'
  ], [
    'win',
    'tie',
    'lose'
  ], [
    'lose',
    'win',
    'tie'
  ]
]

const result = results[rock][paper] // 'lose'
```